# How do I install RSelenium on raspberry pi 3 (raspbian)?

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3, rselenium

I'm trying to install the RSelenium package on my Raspberry Ri Rstudio-server but I get alot of error messages when I try to install the package, some of them are posted below. How do I solve this problem?

```
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:141: recipe for target 'RcppExports.o' failed
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1

ERROR: compilation failed for package 'semver'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/semver'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'semver' had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency 'semver' is not available for package 'binman'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/binman'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'binman' had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies 'binman', 'subprocess', 'semver' are not available for package 'wdman'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/wdman'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'wdman' had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies 'wdman', 'binman' are not available for package 'RSelenium'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RSelenium'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'RSelenium' had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score -2):

So... i'm getting the same error today. I've formatted my computer and now i can't install RSelenium anymore. 
i'm running R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
and i've installed r-base and r-base-dev

Try to run in your terminal the following commands:

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

and then install the "binman" package in your R:

install.packages("binman")

then install the dev version of Rselenium from github.
For this, you shoud have installed in your R the devtools package.

after install devtools run:
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly this didn't work for me, as I cannot install binman package.

Comment: My problem was the same as yours and i have solved it just installing libxml2-dev on linux. This allowed me install binman. This didn't work for you?